# Installing Magento 2.0 with Composer

Tags: error, install, password, composer

I have generated a private key on my Magento account. But composer will only let me enter the username (public key) and won't allow me enter the password (private key). Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use this command in terminal to set public key and private key when need authentication to Magento Connect in Composer

```
composer global config http-basic.repo.magento.com username <public_key> 
composer global config http-basic.repo.magento.com password <private_key>
```

After, you can check config in Composer when using:

```
composer global config --list
```

In normally, it save in `/home/<USERNAME>/.composer/auth.json`